# Use of the tetragrammaton in other names

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names

One of the most striking things to me about Jewish practice is the reverence shown for the Tetragrammaton and, I suppose by extension, all other ways of referring to the Creator. It occurred to me recently (following the death of Leonard Cohen), that the Name is incorporated into various other words, as in “Hallelujah”. (That transliterated word is what appears in the NJPS translation of Psalm 150.) Then of course there are biblical names that incorporate the Tetragrammaton either in part or in whole (Elijah, Isaiah, Jehoshaphat, etc.).

The question is, do these Tetragrammaton-incorporating names receive any special treatment in Jewish tradition? Has there been any reflection on the significance of the Tetragrammaton appearing in these names?

(“Has there been any reflection?”—from previous experience in this site, I know that this must all have been worked out thousands of years ago; I just don't know where to look for the answer.)

Comment: Note that Hallelujah incorporates the name "jah"; not the tetragrammaton itself. Same for Eli**jah**, and Isaiah.

Comment: Also note that in many texts halleluyah is written as two words: hallelu yah.

Comment: Have you ever heard someone say "Yisrakel" or "Shmukel?"

Comment: @ezra there were those, that when writing those names put a dash between the א and the ל

Comment: @mroll - It is true that I have seen that but the names are still pronounced the same.

Comment: Backing up @mroll, it is a practice in some groups to put a dash between aleph and lamed, or yud and heh. I have also heard someone refer to a Cambridge college as Immonukel, although the drinking of ginger kel has more of a joke (Purim?) status.

Comment: @mevaqesh I've always assumed that “jah” was just a shortening of the tetragrammaton (which I would assume requires the same level of respect?). Is there another way to interpret it?

Comment: @adam.baker I wouldn't be surprised if the two are related, but that doesn't mean they are identical. I admit ignorance on the matter.

Comment: @mevaqesh I should have thought of this before, but “Yah” is used various places in the Bible—in Psalm 77:12, for instance. Both the Septuagint and the NJPS translation (to take two translations widely separated in time and space) translate “Lord”, which is the standard translation of the Tetragrammaton.

Comment: @adam.baker Certainly they both refer to God, the question is whether they carry the exact same connotation.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an article on the following website that may answer your question. It is too extensive to quote here so I have simply included a link the webpage.

https://thinkingyid.com/2016/10/07/the-tetragrammaton/

**Note:** The author of the article has stated that the words formatted in Hebrew are not displaying properly on the site but there is a PDF version (with the correct Hebrew lettering) linked at the bottom of the article page.

Comment: Are you the author of that site?

Comment: I help manage the site's technical side. The site has been created by a small group of people wishing to create a medium through which members of our community can express their thoughts and ideas without fear of criticism or ostracization. It is different than other sites because one does not have to be a professional writer or scholar to contribute. It is open to all who wish to contribute.

Comment: I'm down-voting because I don't see anything in that link relevant to my question (aside from veneration of the Tetragrammaton).

Comment: You asked if there was any special treatment given. The article clearly states ways in which it is used by certain members of Judaism and that is is considered "significant". I am unsure why you think there is no relevance to your question...

Comment: Okay, maybe very *very* indirectly, if what I asked about is assumed to be an instance of what is discussed on that page. But there's no mention of the Tetragrammaton being incorporated into other words.